# C2065 identifier undeclared

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, identifier

In my Service.h I have:

```
#include "Configuration.h"
```

and in my class:

```
private:
ConfigurationInterface* configuration_;
```

Then, in my Service.cpp:

```
Service::Service(Foundation::Framework* framework) : 
        framework_(framework)
    {

  configuration_ = new Configuration();
    }
```

and later...

```
 const Info GetInfo()
 {
  return configuration_->getInfo();
 }
```

I get undeclared identifier error.... (configuration_)

Why¿?

**EDIT**: As Cedric H. said: "ConfigurationInterface is an abstract class and Configuration inherit from it"

Comment: Please post a minimal compilable source along with the exact error.

Comment: which identifier does it say is undeclared? What line does the error appear on?

Comment: every line that configuration_ is used...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an 'undeclared identifier' error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197030/what-is-an-undeclared-identifier-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
const Info GetInfo()
```

to

```
const Info Service::GetInfo()
```

Comment: Without the class qualification on the function the compiler thinks this is a global function rather than a class member function, and therefore it has no idea what configuration_ is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

configuration_ = new ConfigurationInterface();

Comment: But maybe ConfigurationInterface is an abstract class and Configuration inherit from it ?