# Cannot compile and locate the error

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code to find the beginning of a loop in a linked list. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        node* next;
    };
    node* head;
    LinkedList() : head(NULL){};
    void AppendToTail(T data);
    void InsertToHead(T data);
    void RemoveDuplicates();
    void PrintList();
    T lastNthNode(int N);
    bool operator==(const LinkedList<T>& L);
    node* FindBeginningNodeLoop();
};

template <class T>
node* LinkedList<T>::FindBeginningNodeLoop()
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    node* slow = head;
    node* fast = head;
    while (fast->next != NULL)
    {
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next->next;
        if (slow == fast)
            break;
    }
    if (fast == NULL)
        return NULL;

    slow = head;
    while (slow != fast)
    {
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next;
    }
    return slow;
}
```

The compiler gives the following errors:

1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users...\linkedlist.h(177): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users...\linkedlist.h(177): error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users...\linkedlist.h(177): error C2923: 'LinkedList' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
1>c:\users...\linkedlist.h(200): error C2509: 'FindBeginningNodeLoop' : member function not declared in 'LinkedList'
1>          c:\users...\linkedlist.h(5) : see declaration of 'LinkedList'

I cannot find the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Here is the only error message from my compiler, verbatim.

`blah.cpp:24:1: error: unknown type name 'node'
node* LinkedList<T>::FindBeginningNodeLoop()`

Comment: There are only 47 lines in the code you posted. Where is line 177?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an 'undeclared identifier' error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197030/what-is-an-undeclared-identifier-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The code was compiling with no errors until I added FindBeginningNodeLoop() function. I knew that the problems were related with this function only.

Answer (score 2):

`node` is an inner type of `LinkedList`. You have twooptions:

use trailing return type, where the return type is in the scope of the class:

```
LinkedList<T>::FindBeginningNodeLoop()->node* { .... }
```

Or use the class's scope when referring to it outside of the class definition:

```
template <class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::node* LinkedList<T>::FindBeginningNodeLoop() { .... }
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

On top of that you need to use `typename` to specify that `node` is a type (see [*when is the `typename` keyword necessary*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary) for more information.)

The second version is required if your compiler does not support C++11 or c++14.

Comment: don't forget the `typename`

Comment: Thank you very much! Code compiled with no problems!

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that a trailing return type `-> node*` would also work, with less noise.

Comment: @MikeSeymour given c++11.

Answer (score 1):

You declared struct `node` within `LinkedList` class.  The name `node` is not visible by itself, it should be preceded by `LinkedList<T>::` every time it is used outside class definition.

Also, it will require using the `typename` keyword to make the distinction between the type and an (eventually existing) variable of the same name.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now the code compiled with no errors.

Comment: That's not why `typename` is required. There's no mention of a variable of the same name in the code in the question and there is no reason for such  variable to exist. `typename` is required because `node` is a *dependent* name.

Comment: Well, going to the details of the standard terminology is an overkill when the question is "I can't debug a simple template".

Comment: Well, If you don't want to scare OP with big words, then maybe you could just state that `typename` is required for reasons that they don't need to concern themselves with yet. I don't see how the incorrect statement about a variable of the same name helps.