# Error creating simple instance of class in Visual studio in C++. Beginner

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class

Just trying to make my first instance of a class in Visual Studio in C++ but it always leads to error code C2065. Here is my Code:

What am I forgetting? I think this should work:

```cpp
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World" << endl;
  Testerus a;
}

class Testerus {
  int a =3;
}
```

Comment: Try to define your class `Testerus` before the main() function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an 'undeclared identifier' error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197030/what-is-an-undeclared-identifier-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: For future questions about build errors, please copy-paste the full and complete build output into the question. Not everyone know the MSVC error codes by heart.

Comment: As for the problem with the code you show, what resources are you using to learn C++? If it doesn't tell you that symbols must be declared (or maybe even defined) before you use the symbols, then perhaps you should consider another resource to learn.

Answer (score 0):

In your main function you have used **extra '{' curly brace** in your code plus you have not used semicolon for class definition

```
class Testerus
{
   int a =3;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World" << endl;
  Testerus a;
}
```

Comment: @tridentifer Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.
Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.